# Computer crashed, workspace in Eclipse lost

Tags: eclipse, workspace

My computer with Windows crashed but I managed to reboot it with Ubuntu and access the Eclipse folder. There were still files and folders in there but not the workspace folder. The workspace folder and all its contents are gone so I wonder if there is any way to restore it. If it is relevant, the .p2, .m2 and .eclipse folders are still there. When I looked around it seemed that it is possible to restore things with the metadata but that seems to require the workspace folder to be there.

Comment: Are you sure the workspace folder was in the eclipse folder in the first place? That would be a very odd location. When you try to start eclipse, what workspace location does it use by default? Have you tried a file search?

Comment: Yes, I am quite positive that it was in the Eclipse folder in the first place. I am quite new to programming so I just put it there when I installed Eclipse. After that I kept it as default workspace. I also searched for it but with no result. I am trying a more extended search now. 
Thank you for the fast asnwer.

Comment: Also try searching for any `*.java` files (or better: one of the files you were recently working on)